# Executing queries in a JavaSparkStreamingContext

Tags: java, apache-spark, neo4j, spark-streaming

I have a program which works with Spark `JavaStreamingContext`. I have learnt that there are just a few output operations admitted when using DStreams, as `print()`.
This is a piece of code

```
private static void analyzeHashtags() throws InterruptedException {
    JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages =  KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zookeeper_server, kafka_consumer_group, topics);
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> lines = messages.mapToPair((x)->(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(x._2, 1))).reduceByKey(sumFunc);
    lines.print();
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();

}
```

Now I'd like to add queries operation to this code, like below:

```
private static void analyzeHashtags() throws InterruptedException, SQLException {
    JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages =  KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zookeeper_server, kafka_consumer_group, topics);
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> lines = messages.mapToPair((x)->(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(x._2, 1))).reduceByKey(sumFunc);
    lines.print();
    String hashtag = "#dummy"; int frequencies = 59;
    String cql = " CREATE (n:Hashtag {name:'"+hashtag+"', freq:"+frequencies+"})";
    st.executeUpdate(cql);
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

But this code just executes the query once. I'd like it to execute it every time it loops.
How is it possible to make this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute arbitrary operations on a DStream, we use `foreachRDD`. It provides access to the data at each batch interval, represented by the underlying rdd.

Java/Scala pseudo(mix)code:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> lines = messages.mapToPair((x)->(new 
Tuple2<String, Integer>(x._2, 1))).reduceByKey(sumFunc);
lines.foreachRDD{ rdd => 
    .. do something with the RDD here...
}
```

Normally, the `do something` operates on the data on the RDD.
We can either operate on that data in a distributed way, by using RDD functions such as `foreachPartition`.

But, considering that you're using a local neo4j connection here, and if the data at each streaming interval is not very large, we can collect the data to the driver and do the operation locally. It seems that would be a fit in this case, as the data has passed already a distributed reduce phase (`reduceBykey`)

So, the `foreachRDD` part would become:

```
lines.foreachRDD{ rdd => 
    val localDataCollection = rdd.collect
    localDataCollection.foreach{ keywordFreqPair => 
      val cql = "CREATE (n:Hashtag {name:'"+keywordFreqPair._1+"', freq:"+keywordFreqPair._2+"})"
      st.executeUpdate(cql)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete and useful answer.
I just don't know how to implement the `foreachRDD` part in Java (idk Scala). Using a lambda expression, should I write `lines.foreachRDD(rdd->(...` with a function in place of dots?

Comment: I personally recommend using Scala with Spark Streaming. For the Java translation of the `foreachRDD` lambda, I think you can find an example in the Spark Streaming  example pkg. e.g.: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaSqlNetworkWordCount.java